# UIWebView On Button Click Event

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone

I have done this Example for implementation of the WebView. [here is the link](http://staging.icodeblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/icodebrowser1.zip)

But in My application i want to set it to load on the Button click event.
If the Above link Example there is no any xib file needed. But in My Application i have made the XIB file to load. So How can i implement it on My own XIB file on button pressed Event ???

Comment: so you want to know how to make a web view load on a button click? Is that what your saying? Sorry, its just hard to make out...

Comment: Yes, Thats what i am saying. And Thanks for your reply. but i have made it. its not to hard. Just Follow this Link : http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/12/19/iphone-coding-learning-about-uiwebviews-by-creating-a-web-browser/

Comment: Take a new View Controller with there .h and .m file. In your new xib file link the appropriate object and view and then call that Class from any otherView Controller on button pressed Event. you can now get the WebView on the button Click Event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your xib file and use the assistant editor to create an IBAction for your UIButton. Then in the method that is created for you in your .m file instantiate and present the WebView.